# How do I hide the VS Code view bar

Tags: user-interface, hide, customization, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to hide/toggle the view bar (different than sidebar, shown below) in VS Code? Or at least, is there a plan to add a hide feature to this panel?

[image: Picture of the view bar >]

I could not find an option for this anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
View -> Hide Activity Bar
```

Menu entry was changed at some point

```
View -> Appearance -> Hide Activity Bar
```

---

It's also possible to hide it from the context menu.

Command: `workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility`

From Command Palette: `Toggle Activity Bar Visibility`

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible, but the option has several open feature requests against it on github.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1105